# google snippets not showing the price for my product

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api

```
`<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/product">
<div itemprop="name">
naren
</div>
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/review">
<span itemprop="rating">5</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/offer">
<span itemprop="price"> USD 500</span>
</div>

</div>`
```

I am using this code to get the price and the rating for my product.I am getting the rating but the price is not showing.google does however show the information of price on the bottom but no in the search preview/What am i doing wrong?

this is the result from the google snippet that I am getting

```
`Item
Type: http://data-vocabulary.org/product
name = naren
review = Item( 1 )
offers = Item( 2 )
Item 1
Type: http://data-vocabulary.org/review
rating = 5
Item 2
Type: http://data-vocabulary.org/offer
price = USD 500 `
```

please try testing this code to understand what I meant in http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price and currency have to be splitted, replace your code with:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/product">
    <div itemprop="name">naren</div>
    <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/review">
        <span itemprop="rating">5</span>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="currency" content="USD" />
        USD <span itemprop="price">500</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/product">
    <div itemprop="name">naren</div>
    <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/review">
        <span itemprop="rating">5</span>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="currency">USD</span>
        <span itemprop="price">500</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had better luck with schema.org than with data-vocabulary.org.

Try this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/product">
<div itemprop="name">
naren
</div>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/offer">
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="usd">
<span itemprop="price">$500</span>
</div>

</div>
```